Optimizing storage usage in Proxmox + CEPH cluster
My friend and I bought 3 Dell Power Edge R740xd servers (128GB of RAM each) along with 11 SSD of 1TB each and 14 HDD of 14TB each. They are interconnected through 2 switches in two different networks via 1GB ethernet interfaces.
We are wrapping our heads around how to get the best out of the current storage inventory in setting up a decent CEPH-powered Proxmox cluster.
With firstly saying that we have little to no background in this, this is our current arrangement for each server.
2 SSD in RAID1 for mirroring proxmox at the hardware level.
1 SSD for running containers and VMs.
4 HDD for CEPH pools
With the remaining 2 HDDs, use them for Proxmox backup.
God only knows what to use the remaining 2 SSDs for.
I have to say I don't agree with the RAID1 idea. Yes, you get 1-disk fault tolerance, but at the cost of around 4.8TBs in SSD. The OS only requires a recommended space of 32GB per the proxmox docs.
Also, (and again) according to the docs, CEPH managers, monitors and MDS (in case we setup a CEPHfs) perform heavy read and writes per second, so I think they are best placed in SSDs.
Regarding a shared library for sharing files among the 3 servers, I was wondering it was best formatting the disk and share the fs using NFS protocol (with NFS Ganesha?). From what I have read I concluded NFS is better than CephFS for this, it is a more robust, performant and battle-tested proto.
So my question is: If you were us how would you make the best out of this storage for using Proxmox along with CEPH? Consider also that we want to use proxmox backup, you know, for backups.

There are plenty of options, and we don't know what performance requirements there are.
If you intend to use CephFS, it's strongly recommended to have fast storage for the metadata pool, but having only two OSDs is definitely not enough. You might end up in a corner case situation, Ceph is designed to be highly available and easily scalable, too few OSDs is the opposite.
It definitely makes sense to have the MON store on SSDs, otherwise you'll most likely suffer in disaster recovery situations.
The minimal configuration for CephFS would be to have 6 SSD OSDs (they don't need to be large) for the metadata pool, 12 HDDs for the data pool(s) is alright. The metadata pool doesn't require too much space, so maybe you can add a bunch of small SSDs to each server to cover that? If you don't care about performance at all, you can put both metadata and data pools on HDDs, but this might not be what you're looking for.

Wow! You have yourself a real treasure trove of equipment there. Proxmox is made so that the individual node is inconsequential to the overall operation. The more nodes you have the more true that is. Here's how I would configure the 3 systems if they were mine.
Each machine would have 2 SSDs (1 for boot and one for journal). Each machine would have 4 Hard Drives for ceph data. The remaining drives would be spares in the event of a failure.
Install proxmox on each node and consume 1 SSD. Then when you setup your Ceph side of things, you specify about 200G of space on the second SSD as journal for each of the OSDs. Make sure you have very fast networking between the machines for ceph back end to use. If you can, do 40G, you'll get better performance from the cluster. Make sure you have separate networking for the proxmox side of things. This will ensure that your proxmox communication doesn't busy up your ceph comunication side of things. If you really want to go all out, get a 3rd very fast network for moving VMs around. This will greatly speed up things.
Proxmox is a good platform, and can be very fun to operate especially when combined with CEPH. The nice thing is that if your boot SSD fails, you can simply remove the failed node from the cluster, and then join the cluster with the new install on that same node. Using a single command you can bring the ceph OSDs back into the cluster and within minutes CEPH will be all happy.
I hope this gives a little direction.
